Search for centers of generic sets of points (other then the centroid)
I proposed to a group of friends o'mine the following problem for discussion:

Given two finite sets of points $A$ and $B$ on the plane, how to efficiently determine if one is a rotation (not necessarily through the origin) of the other?

We quickly got to a naive approach: Let $X, Y$ be points of $A$. For every pair of points $Z, W$ in $B$, there is at most a single rotation that could possibly take $X$ to $Z$ and $Y$ to $W$. Now we just test if this rotation works out for the rest of the points. We also found a nice optimization for this algorithm. Notice the rotation of the centroid of a set of points is the centroid of the rotation of the same set of points! Therefore, we don't really need to go through every pair of points in $B$. Just fix $X$ in $A$ and, for every point $Z$ in $B$, test the single rotation that could possibly take $X$ to $Z$ and centroid to centroid. But can we do better? Could we just find another point similar to the centroid and test a single rotation, the one that takes centroid to centroid and special point to special point?
The centroid works very well here because of two of its properties:

Its a symmetric function (it doesn't care about the order of its arguments); this is important since otherwise we would have to test several labelings of the points.
Its invariant through rigid transformations (it would be enough to be invariant through rotations, but this is a very straightforward generalization).

Is there another special function that takes a set of points to a single point with both of these properties?
If our set have only three points, then the answer is positive! Any triangle center, such as the circumcenter, incenter and orthocenter, would do. None of these generalize for four or more points, though. Triangles have lots of centers, do larger polygons really get only the centroid?

Just as an extra, what about sets of infinitely many points? Suddenly the centroid is no longer well defined. Is there any special point we can define? Without using the axiom of choice, please. This is pointless if we can't tell the location of the point for a given set.

Update: They exist! Kinda. I've found some examples, such as

the center of the minimal enclosing circle;
the geometric median;
the complex harmonic mean.

However, there is a catch. All of those (plus the centroid) might coincide. In fact, if our set of points have two axis of symmetry, then the only possible symmetric center is their intersection. This explains why none of these centers are well defined for infinite sets, since they could have parallel symmetry axes.
The problem is, therefore, solved for sets that are not too symmetric.

One thought: In addition to centroids, compute the moments of inertia (which are 2x2 matrices); if they are not conjugate then the sets cannot be related; if they are conjugate and not diagonal, then the principal axes would tell you what the rotation must be (well, it would give 2 possibilities 180 degrees apart). If they are diagonal, maybe one can continue by looking at higher moments...

Assume from the start that there are the same number of points in each set, and that neither set is collinear.
If the points are more or less randomly placed then pick any three in $A$ and look for a congruent triangle in $B$. The "more or less random" implies there is just one if there are any. If there is none you are done. If there is one it determines a rigid motion that superimposes the one from $A$ on the one from $B$. If that motion makes all the other points match and has no translation component then you have the rotation you seek.
If the randomness isn't there then there may be several triangles in $B$ that match one from $A$ and you can try them all.
For infinite sets any algorithm will require infinitely many computations since you have to look at every point at least once.

My question regarding infinite sets is no longer concerning the complexity of the algorithm, of course! I just want to know if we can determine a point of reference for a set similar to the centroid.

My answer doesn't address your "point of reference" question. It answers the question you started with, that led to the one you asked.

Take any working construction $P_{ABC}$ for three points $A,B,C$. For a finite set $S$ of distinct points consider
$$P_S := \sum_{\substack{ A,B,C \in S \\ \textrm{distinct}}} P_{ABC}$$
If we take $P_{ABC} =(A+B+C)/3$, you will get a multiple of the centroid. Let's prove that it is invariant under rigid transformation, assuming it holds for the construction over three points. Consider a rigid transformation $r$.
$$P_{rS} := \sum_{\substack{ A,B,C \in rS \\ \textrm{distinct}}} P_{ABC} =$$
$$= \sum_{\substack{ A,B,C \in S \\ \textrm{distinct}}} P_{rA,rB,rC} =$$
$$= \sum_{\substack{ A,B,C \in S \\ \textrm{distinct}}} rP_{A,B,C} =$$
$$= r \left ( \sum_{\substack{ A,B,C \in S \\ \textrm{distinct}}} P_{A,B,C} \right ) = \boxed{rP_S}$$
Voila'! We only used the "covariance" for three points and the linearity of rigid transformations.
Algorithmically, one nice choice could be the incenter, that has the following explicit formula:
$$I(A,B,C) = \left ( \frac{ax_1 + bx_2 + cx_3}{a + b + c}, \frac{ay_1 + by_2 + cy_3}{a + b + c} \right ) $$
However, the corresponding algorithm is cubical, worse than your candidates. One should check if the total summation simplifies...
